# Aiogram.Чтение ссылок из базы данных

Tags: python, sql, aiogram, sqlalchemy

В sqllite3 лежит таблица article с полем link(в нем лежит веб ссылка).
Я динамически генерирую кнопки от количества данных.
Как через inlinekeyboardbuilder или другим спобосом , сделать так , чтобы кнопки при нажатии предлагали открыть веб ссылку?